# Navigation Guard Stopping Me Going to Page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `vue` page I am using a `navigation-guard` on. This is being used as its an *Update Details* page, so I am using `beforeRouteLeave`, which if the details have changed, displays my warning `modal`, but this is where I'm stuck. If I click my 'Disregard Changes' button, I want the `modal` to close and the `navigation` to happen, but I can't get it to work, as I keep getting an error:

> *Navigation aborted from "/myAccount/accountDetails" to "/contactus" via a navigation guard.*

I have tried using `$emit` on `click`, but I can't get my `$on` to trigger in my `component` when my `modal` closes.

**Component**

```js
beforeRouteLeave (to, from , next) {
    if (!this.detailsChanged) {
        next();
    } else {
        next(false);

        let data = {
            fromPage: 'PersonalDetailsPage',
            toPage: '/contactus',
            personalDetails: {
                name: this.pdName,
                comp_name: this.pdCompName,
                ddi: this.pdTelNo,
                ext: this.pdExtNo,
                mob: this.pdMobNo,
                email: this.pdEmailAdd
            }
        };
        
        VueEvent.$emit('show-details-not-saved-modal', data);
    }
}
```

**Whole modal code**

```html
<template>
    <div class="modal fade danger-modal" id="detailsNotSavedModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="detailsNotSavedModal" aria-hidden="true"
            data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content danger-modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header danger-modal-headerfooter justify-content-start">
                    Updated details not saved
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>The details have changed but have not been saved.</p>
                    <p>Are you sure you want to disregard the updated details?</p>
                    <p>Clicking 'Save details' will save the updated details.</p>
                    <p>Clicking 'Disregard changes' will disregard any updated details.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer danger-modal-headerfooter">
                    <button ref="saveButton" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" @click="updateDetails">Save details</button>
                    <router-link :to="navigateTo" tag="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" @click="disregardDetails">Disregard changes</router-link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "DetailsNotSavedModal",

    data() {
        return { 
             passedDetails: [],
             navigateTo: ''
        }
     },

    created() {
        VueEvent.$on('show-details-not-saved-modal', ( passedDetails ) => {
            this.passedDetails = passedDetails;

            console.log('passedDetails', passedDetails)

            this.navigateTo = this.passedDetails.toPage;

            $('#detailsNotSavedModal').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', this.focus);
        });
    },

    methods: {
        focus() {
            this.$refs.saveButton.focus();
        },

        updateDetails() {
            alert('Save clicked')
        },

        disregardDetails() {
            this.$emit('disregard_changes', { detailsChanged: false })

            // Also tried using a button and the below
            // this.$router.push(this.navigateTo);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

As you can see I am `emitting 'disregard_clicked' and I have tried the below everywhere in my` hooks` but it never gets called.

```js
VueEvent.$on('disregard_changes', ( data ) => {
    this.detailsChanged = data;
    console.log('0')
});
```

Basically, I need to stop `navigation` if details changed, display my `modal` if click 'Save'. This will close `modal` and save details. If they click 'Disregard', the `modal` closes, and the user should navigate to `menu` option selected.

Comment: @tony19 Can you send the above an answer as that was it. Now it hits all my `console.logs` i have in my main `component` so now I can set it correctly

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VueEvent.$on('disregard_changes', ...)`, but your component has `this.$emit('disregard_changes', ...)`, which does not emit the event on the event bus in `VueEvent`.

**Solution**: Change `this.$emit` to `VueEvent.$emit`